# Ads for iOS using Multi-OS Engine

Tags: ios, libgdx, admob, intel

How to integrate any of the Ads platforms into Intel Multi-OS Engine project?

I want to use Admob, but if there are any others is ok, I haven't found if there are libraries to display ads using Intel's MOE.